# Complete component reload

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I need one of my own component to completely reload itself when a given event occurs. By this, I mean I need it to load itself as if the page it is contained in was loaded the first time ; this, because I need this particular component to reload and execute a `<script>` it implements.
Is it possible in any way ?

Comment: This is most likely the wrong solution to your problem, also known as an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Perhaps you should [edit] your question to include *why* you need this complete reload versus any other technique, as well as the code you're currently using.

Comment: @sfdcfox - thats what i figured out based on my chat with OP.

Comment: alright, here is a link to my problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55759135/twitter-thread-api-script-doesnt-execute-after-refresh.
This is why I want my script to get reloaded : because else, it doesn't seem to be executed and this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the view by using  `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();`.

documentation [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:refreshView/documentation)

If you just want to refresh a specific component then you can put that in an `aura:if` and toggle its visibility

Comment: thank you. But didn't solve it : when I exit my component's page and get back to it, the `<script>` are not loaded again or don't seem to be executed the same way it is when reloading the entire page. This is why I need to completely reload my component in the `init` method, but using your method in this `init` function just goes in an infinite loop (obviously).

Comment: @metheM,can you not conditionally re-load? why re-load it always

Comment: well I just don't know how to conditionally reload lol

Comment: can you try this instead of refresh view - window.location.reload(true), its not recommended for lightning but just to see if this works

Comment: infinite loop again, though I also tried putting both of the methods you suggested inside an event handler for both of these events : `force:refreshView` and `force:navigateHome` (the latter doesn't even seem to be what I'm looking for, I know that)

Comment: how are you using the script in the page using ltng script tag? did you try the after scripts loaded method?I fundamentally think there is more to this question in terms of what you are trying to do? I am just missing something